# How to view different MS-Access objects from the same database on different monitors?

Tags: microsoft-access

I want to view two different objects from the same MS-Access 2016 database at the same time, each on a different monitor.

I can configure the database to use overlapping windows, but they are constrained to the same MDI frame as the main application window.

I can launch a second instance of MS Access, but I can't open the same database in the second instance (exclusively locked by the first instance).

Is there any way to open an MS Access object (query, table, relationship view, etc.) such that it can be positioned outside of the main application window?

Comment: I assume that you have tried resizing the Access window so that it spans both monitors?

Comment: You can also set up access so that it allows two different accesses.